# How to send a php variable using a url

Tags: php

I want to for example send the `$test` in a url then I want to use `$_GET` ti get the variable.

This is probably a stupid question but if you have another way of doing this then please let me know. By the way I would usually use include for this but I can't use it this time because of some really long reason. The other option I considered was fwrite. The problem with this is that multiple users will be trying to write this files at once. Its just not practical.

Any help or hints will be great. Thanks guys. Sorry for the stupid question

Comment: What's wrong with `$_GET`? That's how you send variables using a URL.

Comment: but can I actually send the variable $test ?

Comment: Yes, you can. It will be available with $_GET["test"].

Comment: So the url  for example www.host/yourscript.php?test=$test    would work then ?

Comment: Well you should be outputting the contents of `$test`.

Answer (score 1):

you should type this in your webbrose

```
www.host/yourscript.php?test=1
```

Comment: No I'm talking about for example www.host/yourscript.php?test=$test

Comment: No it's not posible to do that test=$test, you should use Ajax.

Comment: Ok could you point me in the right direct please. And I think you misunderstood my question at the start. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $test = 1
    $passvar = "mynextpage.php?test=$test";
?>
```

and from the next page you could do

```
<?php
    $passed_var = $_GET['test'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I understand your question now.

You want to use the variable already defined `$test` and pass it in your script somewhere.

If you pass the "variable" through the URI like such: `page.php?a=test`

You can then say...

```
echo "The value of of \$test is " . $$_GET['a'];
```

Example how it works:

```
$test = 'apples'; // your variable
$_GET['a'] = 'test'; // the get variable

echo $$_GET['a']; // the string value of the get value appended to an empty variable
```